# Extending regressions beyond data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, regression

I'm using Matplotlib and Numpy to plot linear regressions on time series plots in order to predict the trends in the future.

Generating the regressions doesn't seem to be particularly difficult, but getting the regression line to extend past the last data point is proving challenging:

[image: time series with linear regressions in iPython Notebook]

How can I extend the regressions?

Comment: Have u consider using the function parameters returned to u and just plotting the line ur self ? Im not by computer to test. If ur using polyfit, u have all the required params.

Comment: Read ing code from fone is lacking....ok....so make new vector of xnums that is longer. Consider using a numpy array for this. List comp is not so cool in mathy code. U ?ight have overfit ur data too....ull find out :)  i would consider using a glm as well if the noise is explainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you evaluate your regression model, you're predicting a value of submissions for the input date. To predict a wider range, you need to increase the range of dates that you're evaluating the model on. I'd also use `np.polyval` instead of the list comprehension, just because as it's more compact:

```
# Generate data like the question
observed_dates = pd.date_range("jan 2004", "april 2013", freq="M")
submissions = np.random.normal(5000, 100, len(observed_dates))
submissions += np.arange(len(observed_dates)) * 10
submissions[::12] += 800

# Plot the observed data
plt.plot(observed_dates, submissions, marker="o")

# Fit a model and predict future dates
predict_dates = pd.date_range("jan 2004", "jan 2020", freq="M")
model = np.polyfit(observed_dates.asi8, submissions, 1)
predicted = np.polyval(model, predict_dates.asi8)

# Plot the model
plt.plot(predict_dates, predicted, lw=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the regression line beyond the data, for example, to cover the entire x range, you can do (just change the last 3 lines):

```
import numpy as np
X=np.arange(xmin, xmax, 50)
line=beta1*X**2+beta2*X+beta3
plt.plot(X, line, 'r-', lw=5.)
```